# Force subclasses to implement two interfaces

Tags: c#

Lets say that I have a class that represents a `Stream` and that I subclass this class to add the methods read and write. These two methods are defined in two separate interfaces `IWriteableStream` and `IReadableStream`.

```
public class MyFooStream : Stream, IWriteableStream, IReadableStream
```

How can I force the developer who subclasses from `Stream` to implement the interfaces so that I can enforce the idea that all `Stream` must be readable and writeable?

EDIT: So my solution has been to make `Stream` abstract and implement the two interfaces. Then the interfaces methods are marked as abstract in `Stream` forcing subclasses to implement them.

```
public abstract class Stream : IWriteableStream, IReadableStream
{
    public abstract void WriteToStream();
    public abstract void ReadFromStream();
}

public class WaterStream : Stream
{
    public override void WriteToStream() {}
    public override void ReadFromStream() {}
}
```

Comment: Did you write `Stream`? I'm assuming no of you'd just implement the interface one layer up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make `MyFooStream` an abstract class, and 'implement' those methods on the abstract class as abstract methods - all derived classes will have to have implementations for those methods.

Answer (score 2):

If the interface methods are implemented in the base class then any derivation of `Stream` will inherit these and as such already be implementing both `IWritableStream` / `IReadableStream`.

If you want to force them to *override* the default behaviour, then you could make `read`/`write` methods abstract (or the entire class if need be).

**Example**

```
public class MyFooStream : Stream, IWritableStream, IReadableStream
{
    public abstract void Write(byte[] data);
    public abstract byte[] Read();
}

// if I don't override Write/Read methods the compiler will complain
public class ReadableStream : MyFooStream
{
    public override void Write(byte[] data)
    {
        ...
    }

    public override byte[] Read()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```